# iframe web-pages not displaying on mobile devices correctly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, iframe, heroku

I have an interesting problem regarding iframes. I have built a couple of web pages using rails, deployed them to Heroku, and have succesfully iframed them into an existing site that i am updating. They look great on desktop but are not working at all on mobile devices. They look completely fine in chrome inspect element when testing on the different mobile devices, the media queries kick in when they should etc, and on a safari browser they look correct also, but on an ACTUAL iphone, they don't display correctly at all. This makes it so hard to test what is going wrong and i'd love for someone here to be able to work out the issue for me.

The pages i'm referring to can be found at http://www.socialplayground.com.au/gifgif and http://www.socialplayground.com.au/roaming_selfie. Please find the code below:

---

Both gifgif and roaming selfies pages index.html layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden;height: 100%;">

    <iframe src="https://aqueous-cliffs-8274.herokuapp.com/gifgif" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

---

application controller in Rails

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception


  private
    def allow_iframe
      response.headers.delete "X-Frame-Options"
    end
end
```

---

pages controller in Rails

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    after_filter :allow_iframe

    def gifpage
    end

    def selfies
    end
end
```

The first three here is how it appears on ios mobile as you scroll
[image]

[image]

[image]

This is what it should look like
[image: This is what it should look like]

Comment: Hm, I see exactly the same on my android device, as in on my pc (Chrome 46.0.2490 on Android 5.0.2). Can you attach a screenshot? Is it failing on Safari only?